# GWT click handler is ignored if value change handler is added to a text field

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT form with a Text Field and a disabled "save" button.
when user starts typing anything in the text field, I want to enable "Save" button. then a single click on the "save" button should invoke some save() code.

I added

1. ClickHandler to the Save button.
2. "Value change handler" to the text
   field to update the backing model. Unfortunately, it is only invoked
   when the field loses FOCUS, so I also had to add:
3. KeyPressHandler to
   the text field to enable Save button when user starts typing.

so I start typing in the text field (I see KeyPressHandler gets invoked and Button becomes enabled), then I click "save".

at this moment GWT fires "focus lost" event and my Value Change Handler gets invoked and the backing model gets updated. but the event for ClickHandler gets lost! it's simply not invoked.
I have to click "save" button again, then save() finally gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

ValueChange handler is for detecting change of value of the field.

The value change is not registered until you provide a gesture to the text field that you have completed typing in the field and want to register the change. I believe the gesture would be either a CR or loss of focus.

OTOH, the handler that you might wish to attach to the text field is a keyup handler ( http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpHandler.html ), so that on every key-up your code could check the value of the key that had just been entered.

But, why would you want to do that? Why not stay with the value change handler? You have to move your mouse off the text field anyway to reach the mouse button.

Comment: the problem is that when I move the mouse to click "save" button, event change handler is executed, but "button clicked" event is lost. so the model gets an update, but I have to click "save" twice. does not make sense. I'm sure I'm not using all these listeners correctly (my 1st gwt attempt)...